# quit application running from usb drive if usb is removed

Tags: c++, qt, usb

As the title says I have an application which runs on a USB drive. if the USB drive is removed the application should close. it would also be ok to just let the application crash but the error window (...exe stopped working) should be suppressed. At the moment there is an error that the application crashed when I remove the USB drive. I tried to do this with a thread checking if the drive is still inserted but this doesn't work.

```
while(running){
    bool found = false;
    auto drivesList = QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes();
    for(auto& drive : drivesList){
        if(drive.rootPath() == storage){
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        application->quit();
    }
}
```

this is how I check if I should quit the application in a separate thread. `storage` is a QString with the drive `rootpath`.

Comment: do it like software on CDs: copy your executable and all non-static files to a temporary directory on startup, start the copy and exit. the copy could then test if the original executable file still exists.

Comment: thats a nice idea :) but do you think copying those files would be fast enough? and a dumb question: what are the non-static files @markus-nm

Comment: Files that are or might be dynamically mapped by the system, like application libraries (dll), and files that you need to write to, like database files. I'd probably copy static / resource files if you need to have them opened for longer than reading them once, like the translation files or fonts etc.

Comment: thank you that you tried to help me. i found a solution. my application is now copying a batch file and a exe from the usb drive. the exe kills the application if the usb drive is ejected. the batch file then deletes the exe and itself. @markus-nm